Chevalley's constructibility theorem: from the Noetherian to the general case
Chevalley's theorem on constructible sets usually circulates in two different versions:

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a scheme morphism of finite type, $Y$ noetherian. Then the image of any constructible set $A \subseteq X$ under $f$ is constructible in $Y$ (where constructibility is defined only via closeds and opens).
Let $f : X \to Y$ be a scheme morphism of finite type. Then the image of any locally constructible set $A \subseteq X$ under $f$ is locally constructible in $Y$ (where the definition of constructibility is defined via retrocompactness, see e.g. the Stacks project).

Judging by a couple of sources, the former seems significantly easier to prove. Does anyone know a way to use it to prove the latter?
For the most part it should be sufficient to limit ourselves to the affine case: let $B$ be a finitely generated $A$-algebra and $f : \operatorname{Spec}(B) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ the induced map, $A,B$ integral rings. Can we show that $f$ preserves constructibility from the first version of the theorem?
Grothendieck seems to take a similar route in EGA IV 1.8.5, but it's unclear to me how he seems to arrive at the Noetherianness hypothesis.
